# How to find top 5 values in mongodb ? and should not contain same value

Tags: mongodb

I have data in DB something like this

```
    [
       { Appname:ktr, softcount:10 ,timeStamp:1 },
       { Appname:rsr, soscount:8,timeStamp:2 },
       { Appname:ktr, softcount:9 ,timeStamp:3},
       { Appname:ssl, softcount:6,timeStamp:4},
       { Appname:ktr, softcount:7,timeStamp:5 },
       { Appname:ppr, softcount:5,timeStamp:6},
       { Appname:crs, softcount:4,timeStamp:7 },
       ............

    ]
```

here  `Appname` key will contain the value which is unknown value .
`Appname` might be anything .

I need to find top 5 softcount record based on the timerange and that too should not contain the same `Appname`

To find the top 5 values , I have used this query

```
  db.collection.find({timeStamp : { $gte : startTime, $lte :endTime}}).sort({'softcount':-1}).count(5)
```

here startTime is 1 and endTime is 7

it is give top 5 `softcount` record but record contains same `Appname` . so

i want the result something like this from db

```
[
  {Appname:ktr,softcount:10,timeStamp:1},
  {Appname:rsr,softcount:8,timeStamp:2},
  {Appname:ssl,softcount:6,timeStamp:4},
  {Appname:ppr,softcount:5,timeStamp:6},
  {Appname:crs,softcount:4,timeStamp:7}
]
```

in this result Appnames are not same  it does not contain the same `Appname` .

is it possible to write mongodb query ?

what is the query to get above record ?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can use aggregation pipeline to group and project data in format you want to see.

```
db.col.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:"$Appname", softcount:{$max:"$softcount"}}},
{$project:{_id:0, "Appname":"$_id", softcount:1}},
{$sort:{softcount:-1}},
{$limit: 5}
])
```

this will print following result, provided input is what you mentioned in your question.

```
{ 
    "softcount" : 10.0, 
    "Appname" : "ktr"
}
{ 
    "softcount" : 8.0, 
    "Appname" : "rsr"
}
{ 
    "softcount" : 6.0, 
    "Appname" : "ssl"
}
{ 
    "softcount" : 5.0, 
    "Appname" : "ppr"
}
{ 
    "softcount" : 4.0, 
    "Appname" : "crs"
}
```

You can learn more about MongoDB aggregation framework at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

Comment: Thank you it is useful . I need to find the data based on some timerange before doing aggregation so if i use find({ timeStamp : { $gte : startTime, $lte : endTime}})  menthod it is giving data but i can not do aggregation after this so how to use find() method inside aggregation ?

Comment: Please update your question with real sample data including timestamp. it's difficult to say anything without looking at data. however, in aggregation framework, you can limit data by using $match operator. its job is like HAVING clause in relational world.

Comment: $match:{ timeStamp : { $gte : startTime, $lte : endTime}} i am thinking this will help ..to confirm that i asked you...

Comment: Cool, be sure that you use $match in beginning of aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregation `$first`

[link here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)

Who is too lazy to look at it :

This data in collection `sales`

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:05:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T09:05:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 6, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T12:05:10Z") }
{ "_id" : 7, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T14:12:12Z") }
```

Can be aggregated as following

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort: { item: 1, date: 1 } },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$item",
           firstSalesDate: { $first: "$date" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Giving us this result

```
{ "_id" : "xyz", "firstSalesDate" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:05:00Z") }
{ "_id" : "jkl", "firstSalesDate" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : "abc", "firstSalesDate" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z") }
```

Comment: You forgot the last pipeline stage `{ "$limit": 5 }`

Comment: I did not, I showed him "how to do group by with first", not concrete solution, he can pipeline it, he can set limit etc.