# MongoDB query does not display the value to a field I queried for

Tags: mongodb

Right so I was trying to make a query to find the planes with the top 5  highest altitudes. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745865/how-to-find-top-5-values-in-mongodb-and-should-not-contain-same-value)

And I got the plane names that flew the top 5 altitudes, however, the actual altitude is [not displayed](https://puu.sh/zQ22D/118768153e.png)

Anybody have any theories why that may be?

My code:

```
db.planes.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:"$hex_id", altitude:{$max:"$altitude"}}},
{$sort:{altitude:-1}},
{$limit: 5}
])
```

EDIT: Found that replacing $hex_id (same as flight_id in the data set) displayed just the altitude, but now the flight number. So I need to figure out how to get both to appear at once. Working on that now.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Sample dataset:

```
msg_dummy   msg_type    flight_id   aircraft_id date    time    latitude    longitude   altitude    ground_speed    heading dummy1
MSG 1   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74233                       
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74234   29.19579    -80.97435   37975           
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74234   29.19458    -80.97398   37975           
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74237   29.18979    -80.97247   37975           
MSG 4   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74237   29.18979    -80.97247   37975   449 164 0
MSG 1   N192NC  A170C8  20130911    74239                       
MSG 4   N192NC  A170C8  20130911    74240       456 359 -64     
MSG 4   N192NC  A170C8  20130911    74241       456 359 -64     
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74242   29.17894    -80.96902   38000   449 164 0
MSG 4   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74242   29.17894    -80.96902   38000   449 164 0
MSG 4   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74242   29.17894    -80.96902   38000   449 164 0
MSG 1   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74243   29.17894    -80.96902   38000   449 164 0
MSG 1   N192NC  A170C8  20130911    74243       456 359 -64     
MSG 4   N192NC  A170C8  20130911    74244       457 359 -64     
MSG 3   N192NC  A170C8  20130911    74244   29.94985    -81.14469   41000   457 359 -64
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74244   29.17494    -80.96773   38000   449 164 0
MSG 4   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74244   29.17494    -80.96773   38000   449 164 0
MSG 4   N192NC  A170C8  20130911    74244   29.94985    -81.14469   41000   457 359 -64
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74245   29.17392    -80.96744   38000   449 164 0
MSG 4   N192NC  A170C8  20130911    74245   29.94985    -81.14469   41000   457 359 -64
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74245   29.17273    -80.96702   38000   449 164 0
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74246   29.17173    -80.96671   38000   449 164 0
MSG 4   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74246   29.17173    -80.96671   38000   449 164 0
MSG 4   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74247   29.17173    -80.96671   38000   449 164 0
MSG 4   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74247   29.17173    -80.96671   38000   449 164 0
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74247   29.1681 -80.96558   38000   449 164 0
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74248   29.1671 -80.96528   38000   449 164 0
MSG 4   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74250   29.1671 -80.96528   38000   449 164 0
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74251   29.16088    -80.96331   38000   449 164 0
MSG 3   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74253   29.15666    -80.962 38000   449 164 0
MSG 4   N192NC  A170C8  20130911    74254   29.94985    -81.14469   41000   457 359 -64
MSG 4   AAL233  AC3558  20130911    74255   29.15666    -80.962 38000   449 164 0
```

Comment: please provide sample data set

Comment: Please provide data in JSON format.

Comment: How do I do that? >.>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.planes.aggregate([
 {$match:{"altitude":{$gte:0}}},
 {$group:{_id:"$hex_id", altitude:{$max:"$altitude"}}},
 {$sort:{rating:-1}},
 {$limit: 5}
])
```

You probably missing the `match` condition, unless you add it, empty values will also be considered and may hits the top while sorting. There may even be chances that particular field is not present in documents.

Unless you provide me a sample data in JSON format, I can't help out much. You should be dealing with JSON/BSON format if you are working with MongoDB.

Comment: This fixed both the null issue and the altitude not appearing! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below

```
db.planes.aggregate([
 {$match:{"altitude":{$gte:0}}},
 {$group:{_id:"$_id", "altitude":{$first:"$altitude"}}},
 {$sort:{altitude:-1}},
 {$limit: 5}
])
```